# Swift: How do I create a custom UINavigationBar and add a custom back button?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to create a custom navigationBar.

I am hiding the original navigationBar in viewWillAppear like so:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}
```

---

I am subclassing UINavigationBar like so:

```
let navBar: UINavigationBar = {
    let view = UINavigationBar()
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    view.isTranslucent = true
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()
```

In viewDidLoad I am calling setupNavBar():

```
func setupNavBar() {
    view.addSubview(navBar)
    self.navBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 80)
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named:"backThick"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(popControllerOffStack))       
}
```

The problem is that backButton is added to the original navigationBar that is being hidden. This makes me think I am incorrectly creating the navigationBar. How do I add the button to navBar?

---

Updated Code (still not working):

```
class CustomNavBar: UINavigationBar {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}

// In the viewController 

let navBar = CustomNavBar()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupNavBar()
}

func setupNavBar() {
    view.addSubview(navBar)
    navBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 80)
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named:"backThick"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(popControllerOffStack))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
}
```

The button is being added to the original navigationBar.

[image]

Comment: If your only intent for creating a custom nav bar is a custom back button, you do not need subclassing.

Answer (score 4):

You are not subclassing `UINavigationBar`. Rather, you are creating a new instance of UINavigationBar and modifying its properties inside a computed variable. This means each time you access `navBar`, you are initializing a new `UINavigationBar` object.

To create a subclass:

```
class MyCustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {
    // Set properties in here after initialization
}
```

Once you have a proper subclass created, You can initialize an instance like so:

```
var navBar = MyCustomNavigationBar()
```

Finally, add your button to the navigation bar:

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named:"backThick"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(popControllerOffStack))  
// Assuming 'self' is an instance of UINavigationController()     
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

See the official [Swift Programming Language Guide on Inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-ID195).

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

You can set custom Back button as like below

```
  self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "image_name"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(Class.methodName))
    backButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try below code:

```
let btnLeftMenu: UIButton = UIButton()
btnLeftMenu.setImage(UIImage(named: "image_name"), for:UIControlState())
btnLeftMenu.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveImage), for:UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
btnLeftMenu.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnLeftMenu)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton*
```